# What is the need of external server in ASP.NET Core outprocess hosting?

Tags: asp.net-core, webserver, kestrel

In OutOfProcess hosting model, there are 2 web servers i.e. one internal web server and one external web server. The internal web server is called Kestrel and the external web server can be IIS, Apache, or Nginx.

When Kestrel is the cross-platform web server for the ASP.NET Core application, and support request from all platforms, then what is the use of external web server?

Answer (score 1):

The IIS or apache contains a lot of advanced feature. For example, advanced logging, GUI ,failed request trancing and other feature. It is very easy to configure and find the logs more easily.

The Kestrel need all settings by the codes and if you need special feature, you need to develop by yourself or changing the codes.